# Garamond / Garamont with bold words?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I am using EB Garamond as body font on my blog. In the articles I want to emphasize words by setting them bold. The bold Garamond looks really ugly. After investigating I found out, that there is no bold version of Garamond. Is there a match for a Bold Garamond?

I am using this font library for the site. http://brick.im/fonts/ebgaramond/

Comment: While EB (whoever that prefix represents) may not have created the variant, bold versions of Garamond certainly do exist. Have you searched for them?

Comment: For an explanation of the “EB,” see http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/.  I’m sure you’ve seen the bold Garamonds available for purchase; if you’re looking for a free font, try https://github.com/rbrito/urw-garamond (the medium is bold enough).

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on using your EB Garamond for the non bold text and use another font for the bold text, you might end up with some issue and inconsistencies. This is just a suggestion but it might be easier to simply find another font that offers you the bold as well.

Another alternative: If your text isn't 100% black but gray, you can add emphasis by making the bold text fully black or darker. There's also the underline... but that's not always the most stylish option.

**If you really want to stick to Garamond...:**

## [Adobe Garamond Pro](https://typekit.com/fonts/adobe-garamond-pro) (TypeKit $)

[image: Adobe Garamond Pro TypeKit]

## [Garamond](http://www.webtype.com/font/garamond-family/) (WebType $)

[image: Garamond webtype]

---

## › FREE Alternative Google Webfont (similar)

## [Amiri Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Amiri)

[image: Amiri Google Font]

## [Crimson Text Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Crimson+Text)

[image: Crimson Text font google]